# Sound card not detected by ALSA, but detected by kernel

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

Running arch linux with:

```
Linux hunchback 3.17.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 21 21:14:42 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When i run:

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

But it is detected by kernel:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfebf4000 irq 26

$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0  
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0887
Subsystem Id: 0x10438445
Revision Id: 0x100302
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
....

$ ls -l /dev/snd/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       60 Jul  7 17:29 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  2 Jul  7 17:29 controlC0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  7 Jul  7 17:29 hwC0D0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  4 Jul  7 17:29 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  3 Jul  7 17:29 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  5 Jul  7 17:29 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  6 Jul  7 17:29 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  1 Jul  7 17:29 seq
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 33 Jul  7 17:29 timer
```

Comment: Is your user a member of the `audio` group? (Run `groups` as the user to find out.) If not, use `adduser` to add yourself to the group, log out and log back in, and `aplay -l` should work.

Comment: Is pulseaudio running? does `pactl list` show it?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue recently, following the comments I was able to solve it.

Make sure that you are part of the `audio` group, so you can access the pulseaudio server (I was able to list the devices with `aplay -l` only as root, not as a normal user).

You can add a user to the audio group with:

```
sudo usermod --append --groups audio <username>
```

**The user needs to log out and log in again for the effects to be applied.**

Comment: I posted [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419196/103271) in this board, and your answer contributed equally to the solution to my problem as the "correct" one I got to my question. Just wanted to tell you that.

Comment: @Multisync Happy it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been trying to solve this for several days! I was experiencing this issue on a Raspberry Pi with a Focusrite Scarlett USB soundcard where the card was listed by `lsusb` but not by `aplay -l`. The default `pi` user is a member of lots of groups, including `audio`, but I had created a new user without adding it to `audio` and `aplay` couldn't find it.