# no Sound on Arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I recently installed Arch Linux on my DELL Inspiron 7591, and I don't get sound anymore from the speakers or from earphones. Sound is said to be getting redirected to a dummy output.

But if I connect Bluetooth earphones, that works.

I went through a few forum posts and understood nothing.
This is an output of a few things that people have asked for on those forums

```
$ also-info.sh

upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.65
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Wed Mar 31 09:45:37 UTC 2021


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Arch Linux \r (\l) NAME="Arch Linux" PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux" ID=arch HOME_URL="https://www.archlinux.org/" DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.archlinux.org/" SUPPORT_URL="https://bbs.archlinux.org/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.archlinux.org/" LOGO=archlinux


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Dell Inc.
Product Name:      Inspiron 7591
Product Version:   
Firmware Version:  1.9.0
System SKU:        0923
Board Vendor:      Dell Inc.
Board Name:        0M01WJ


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DELL0923:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DLLK0923:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D5:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3400:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:03/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3450:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:04/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:05/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:06/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:07/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:08/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:09/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0a/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0b/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0B00:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:03/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:05/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C04:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:00/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/USBC000:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:09/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.11.10-arch1-1
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         unknown
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.11.10-arch1-1
Library version:    1.2.4
Utilities version:  1.2.4


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes

Jack:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/jackd)
      Running - No


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

--- no soundcards ---


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 31 14:48 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 31 14:48 /dev/snd/timer


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
af_alg
agpgart
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
alienware_wmi
blake2b_generic
bluetooth
bnep
bpf_preload
btbcm
btintel
btrfs
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cec
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
crc16
crc32_pclmul
crc32c_generic
crc32c_intel
crct10dif_pclmul
cros_ec
cros_ec_ishtp
cryptd
crypto_simd
crypto_user
dcdbas
dell_laptop
dell_smbios
dell_smm_hwmon
dell_wmi
dell_wmi_descriptor
dell_wmi_sysman
drm
drm_kms_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
ee1004
fat
fb_sys_fops
fuse
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid_multitouch
hid_sensor_hub
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i915
iTCO_vendor_support
iTCO_wdt
idma64
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_gtt
intel_hid
intel_ish_ipc
intel_ishtp
intel_ishtp_hid
intel_ishtp_loader
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_pch_thermal
intel_pmc_bxt
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_soc_dts_iosf
intel_uncore
intel_wmi_thunderbolt
ip_tables
irqbypass
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libarc4
libcrc32c
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
mousedev
mxm_wmi
nvidia
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
pcspkr
processor_thermal_device
processor_thermal_mbox
processor_thermal_rapl
processor_thermal_rfim
raid6_pq
rapl
rfcomm
rfkill
rng_core
serio_raw
snd
snd_compress
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp
snd_soc_sst_ipc
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soundcore
soundwire_bus
soundwire_cadence
soundwire_generic_allocation
soundwire_intel
sparse_keymap
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
thunderbolt
tpm
tpm_crb
tpm_tis
tpm_tis_core
typec
typec_ucsi
uas
ucsi_acpi
uinput
usb_storage
usbhid
uvcvideo
vfat
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas
xor


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------
```

```
$ lsmod | grep snd >> new.txt

snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_dmic           16384  0
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   102400  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      28672  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               147456  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_soc_skl           180224  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        40960  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  3 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  4 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_intel          57344  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
soundwire_intel        45056  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         172032  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof,dell_laptop
snd_hda_core          106496  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_core          331776  6 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_dmic
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm               147456  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_timer              45056  1 snd_pcm
snd                   114688  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

```
$ systemctl status alsa-state.service

● alsa-state.service - Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/alsa-state.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

```
$ systemctl status alsa-restore.service

● alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

The [kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214514/sound-card-not-detected-by-alsa-but-detected-by-kernel) doesn't detect it as well.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards

--- no soundcards ---
```

```
$ ls -l /dev/snd/

total 0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 31 14:48 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 31 14:48 timer
```

Answer (score 1):

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1965434#p1965434

I found the answer on this forum.
Apparently installing sof-firmware alsa-ucm-conf is all it needed to work.

Comment: sof-firmware made it for me, thanks @SomannaK